# Move elements under a drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

So, let's say I have a list of strings like this on my page:

```
 com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
 com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
 com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
```

Here's the simplified code (php):

```
while (something) {
    .....
    echo '<div class="list">';
    echo '  <ul>';
    echo '      <li class="first">'.$game_name.'</li>';
    echo '      <li class="second">'.$avg_fps.'</li>';
    echo '      <li class="third">'.$testing_time.'</li>';
    echo '  </ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

What I want to do is, when I click on one of the strings, another list appears under it, pushing the rest list elements down (obviously, clicking again would cause the second list to retract). Something like:

```
com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
      samsung
      lg
      alcatel
com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
com.pixowl.thesandbox.android 60 60s
```

Solutions considered:
I could add a $_GET variable when I click and refresh the page, completely redrawing it as desired. This totally works, but I would really like to know if there's a way to do it **without** the refresh. It would look much better if all this action looks like a natural animation.

Thanks.

Comment: An expanding drop-down is very common just using nested lists and some JavaScript. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181244/jquery-dropdown-menu-should-expand-if-parent-is-active)

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to make code for you, we're here to help you fix it.

Comment: I wrote my solution, and it does work. I asked for a better alternative. Not necessarily code, ideas are welcome too